# Reading / Math task for evoking affective states

Tags: emotion, experiment-design, ecg, biofeedback

I plan to measure affective states with bio-sensors. For the affective states I will use engagement, confusion, boredom and frustration. For the bio-sensors I will use ECG and skin conductance.

I will do a study with a couple of participants. I'm thinking about either a reading or math task (on a tablet) which the participants should perform. Of course the task should evoke these affective states. Each participant should work for 30-60min.

Are there some standard ways of designing such tasks (i.e. how to evoke the above affective states with reading or math tasks)? Or is there already a reading / math task available in the literature which was used for evoking these affective states?